# FileInformationFactory GetVirtualizedItemsVector() does not update the file path when folder name is changed in UWP

Tags: uwp, storagefile

I am using for a UWP app the `FileInformationFactory` to retrieve Virtualized vector of Items, which can be either a folder or a file information.
I query the following folder structure on my desktop:

**F0/F1/File1.png**

Hence, I have a folder **F0**, which includes a folder **F1** and the latter has a file **File1.png**.
I set the `IndexerOption.DoNotUseIndexer` (code below), and that is at the origin of the issue. I need to use this option such that I can scan non-indexed USB drives.

The result of the query is displayed in a XAML GridView, and I display the **Path** of each item returned by the query, namely **F1** and **File1.png**.

I do the following:

-Run the app

-Pick folder **F0** which then displays the paths
**F1** and **F1\File1.png** (prefixed by `C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\`)

-I Open File Explorer and rename the folder **F1** to **F1a**. The XAML view is reflected instantly as
 **F1a** and **F1\File1.png**.

This means that the path info is properly propagated to the folder **F1**, but the path of the file in **F1**, file being now in **F1a**, is not updated; it remains **F1\File1.png**.

That is not what I expected, because I expect that the change in name of folder **F1** will propagate the results to all the files and folders it contains, hence the path for **File1.png** should be **F1a\File1.png**

Notice that if, now, I change the name of **File1.png** to **File1a.png** the view updates the result to the correct path for this file **F1a\File1a.png**.

**Question**: How to inform the view that a change in the folder name should also trigger a change in the path of the files and folders in this folder??

Notice that the Photos app from Microsoft suffers from the same problem.

Notice, too, that I checked out the various events of the `CollectionViewSource` and item query, without success as these are not specific about the kind of change which occurred. The only solution is to refresh the whole view with brute force, but that becomes very difficult to the user beyond a certain number of items.

Besides the fact that I am pretty sure that the current behavior is inconsistent, I hope someone could help, either confirm/reject that this is a limitation of the API or and above all point to a solution.
Thank you, here is the code which should run on its own (for `Constants.Thumbnail_Size` set e.g. 96).

```
<Page
x:Class="Virtualization.Scenario4"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ba="using:Windows.Storage.BulkAccess"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="FolderPickerButton" Icon="Folder"
                      LabelPosition="Collapsed" Label="Select Folder"
                      Click="FolderPickerButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarSeparator/>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemCollectionView, Mode=OneWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ba:IStorageItemInformation">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Information, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class Scenario4 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    public Scenario4()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ICollectionView _fileCollectionView;
    private StorageFolder _folder;
    private IStorageQueryResultBase _query;
    public CollectionViewSource CollectionViewSource { get; set; } = new CollectionViewSource();
    public ICollectionView ItemCollectionView
    {
        get { return _fileCollectionView; }
        set
        {
            if (_fileCollectionView != value)
            {
                _fileCollectionView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemCollectionView));
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Information { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private async void FolderPickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _pickedFolder = await PickFolderAsync();
        if (_pickedFolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _folder = _pickedFolder;

        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions { FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep, IndexerOption = IndexerOption.DoNotUseIndexer };

        _query = _folder.CreateItemQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        var _fileInformationFactory = new FileInformationFactory(_query, ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, Constants.Thumbnail_Size,
           ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale, delayLoad: false);

        var _vector = _fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedItemsVector();
        CollectionViewSource.Source = _vector;

        ItemCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.View;
        _query.ContentsChanged += Query_ContentsChanged;
        CollectionViewSource.View.VectorChanged += View_VectorChanged; ;
    }

    private async void Query_ContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            Information.Add($"Contents Changed {sender.Folder.Name} {args}");
        });
    }

    private void View_VectorChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs @event)
    {
        Information.Add($"Vector Changed {@event.CollectionChange} Index: {@event.Index}");
    }


    private static async Task<StorageFolder> PickFolderAsync()
    {
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        };

        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var _pickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        return _pickedFolder;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Additionally, there is another unexpected behavior to say the least. If you delete the folder **F1** (or **F1a** if you renamed it so), the view is not updated. But deleting the file inside this folder will update the view. This is unfortunate as, unless I missed a point, it makes the API not so reliable.

Comment: I tried reproduce your issue, but I missed  `Constants.Thumbnail_Size` instance and  `IStorageItemInformation` class could you  provide us?

Comment: Sorry, the Constants.Thumbnail_Size is a uint, say 96. The class you mention is part of the bulk access API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.bulkaccess.istorageiteminformation, the namespace is already included in the xaml via the alias "ba". Perhaps you should rebuild the project.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I will complete the sample and test again

Comment: I could reproduce this issue but I'm not sure if it is a bug, I will report it to related team.

Comment: Thanks, I will be mostly interested in a solution or workaround, if any.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I edited the question to add an additional bug, perhaps this can be reported, too.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, any solution to this? I would be glad to overcome this issue.

Comment: sorry guys, I have not received any info from team, if I have any updates I will comment below.