# Determine which resource culture fallback has been chosen by Windows 10 in UWP

Tags: uwp, localization, cultureinfo, culture

I have a UWP app with the following Resource files for localization

en

es-ES

fr-CA

fr-LU

I have set in Windows 10's settings the preferred languages in priority order for testing purposes

Italian

French (France)

English (UK)

Hence my OS is currently in the Italian language.

The app displays a `TextBlock` with a `x:Uid="Test"`, where `Test.Text`
is set as a key in each of the resources files, and the value is of the form
`"This is a test coming from es-ES"` for the resource file `es-ES`, etc.

**Running the app shows that fr-LU has been chosen.**

From reading the docs, I understand that the `CurrentUICulture` is set to `fr-FR` for this
app, probably because the Italian resource file is not found, so the second choice is chosen, `fr-FR`,
but then `fr-FR` is not found, hence a sibling is chosen, ending in
`fr-LU`. It seems the system choses this over `fr-CA` because it is the last in the list of the `ManifestLanguages`. I even added a resource file of a non-existing culture, `fr-ZZ`, and it gets selected! That is weird but it is not my problem since I am meant to put only valid cultures.

**Question: How can I determine in code which resource or culture tag has been eventually chosen (fr-LU)?**

I can answer this question the silly way, by setting `Test.Text` to be exactly equal to the culture,
use the resource loader and read the value, to then transform it to a culture or override the primary language. But that is reverse engineering that will strongly depend on a string in my resource files for only that purpose.

I am trying to solve this problem because I am presenting a `Listview` of
the `ManifestLanguages` to allow the user to change languages, and want the language
(here `fr-LU`) to be the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` because this is what the system decided to display upon launch.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running the app shows that fr-LU has been chosen.

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/how-rms-matches-lang-tags), the system will perform resource matching in the order of **1. Exact match; 2. & 3. Region match; 4. Parent match; 5. Sibling match**. In this case, sibling matching is performed. About [sibling match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/how-rms-matches-lang-tags#sibling-match), the document mentions in the event of multiple sibling matches, the last enumerated sibling will be the winner, in the absence of a higher match. Since the order of fr-LU is at the end, so the system chooses it as the display language. fr-ZZ does the same.

> How can I determine in code which resource or culture tag has been eventually chosen (fr-LU)?

You can't directly get the resource which has been chosen, because this is choice of system. If you still want to get it, using **resource loader** is recommended.

Comment: Thank you @Faywang , so the conclusion is to go the silly way, but it is good to know there is no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should tell you which language Windows has chosen for any given resource (replace `DUMMY_RESOURCE` with the name of a resource):

```
ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap["Resources/DUMMY_RESOURCE"]
  .Candidates[0].GetQualifierValue("language")
```

That way you don't actually have to localize the resource `DUMMY_RESOURCE`; it can have the same value for all languages.

You can see what valid resource strings you have pretty easily in the debugger by evaluating the `Results` view.

Comment: No this doesn't work, it returns a comma separated list from the languages on the machine, not the fr-LU from the manifestlanguages in the example above.

Comment: I am using resource files in a folder structure of the form Strings/xx/Resources.resx where xx=en and fr (and whatever you want). Edit these resources to put in a key value pair and relaunch your app, you should see a semi-colon seperated list. Reproducing it is easy, just call QualifierValues in the ctor of the page, for instance in this project https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/LibraryManagement , but do not forget to put in the Strings folder with non-empty resources kvp. Let me know.

Comment: You have a single result perhaps because you have one installed language, and/or you have no intersection between the languages declared in the OS and the ones declared in the resource files. E.g. for en and fr resources, and an OS with languages en-GB, fr-FR and it-It, your method will return the string en-GB;fr-FR, hence italian is skipped. I will look into your answer and will report back, thanks

Comment: I reproed your case, thanks for the tip. I provided the different solution above.

Comment: Your solution is crashing "cannot find resource stuff", I should be able to figure it out but it does not work so far. My folder structure is "Strings/en/resources.resw" and the same for fr. I placed your dummy resource as "Strings/resources.resw", and the "Strings" folder is in the top. I tried MainResourceMap["Resources/Strings/resources"], and MainResourceMap["Strings/resources"] and with the resw extensions. Its crashing so far.

Comment: Sorry, try deleting Strings... I'm not sure how that got into there.

Comment: Still crashing. I will figure out and come back to have a say on your proposal. I feel that it will not return the correct result, though, but it surely is appealing. I will do that job when I will clean up this app; in no more than a few weeks as it needs to go online. I will come back to this thread in any case. Cheers and thanks for the time. If you fancy some interesting problems (to me at least), head on here :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029624/how-to-require-windows-10-to-index-a-usb-key-from-a-uwp-app ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978986/gridview-looses-track-of-items-in-a-notindexed-location-and-many-do-not-get-disp , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939388/fileinformationfactory-getvirtualizeditemsvector-does-not-update-the-file-path :)